# TypeError: X is not a function for a commonjs lib called from modular project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm iOS dev and I started learning JS for a small project. I have an issue with launching [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper) package in modular js app.

I have followed the docs that says:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'})
.then(console.log, console.log);
```

But when I import it inside the .mjs file and run it like so:

```
import * as gplay from 'google-play-scraper';

gplay.app({appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate'})
.then(console.log, console.log);
```

Then I get this error:

```
TypeError: gplay.app is not a function
```

I've spent countless hours on looking for the answer and learning the basics of the JS but as I'm still stuck on the same issue for a long time, I hope some of you would help me understand it faster. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, instead of the internet, compiler has helped me finding the answer. What I did not understand before was how to properly import the exported const(s) from commonjs to modular. This is how I did it:

```
import gplay from 'google-play-scraper';

const { app } = gplay;

app({ appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate' }).then(console.log, console.log)
```

Hope that helps someone in the future